# Docker + python + postgresql и проект с множеством директорий

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, docker

Добрый день. Столкнулся с необходимостью завертывания проекта в Docker. Изучаю и руководство на сайте, и эту замечательную [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/310460/#ownimage). Но есть одна проблема. В статье сказано размещать Dockerfile в папке, где расположено приложение. Но у проекта структура из нескольких папок, в одной из которых расположены исходники на Python. Структура проекта аналогична структуре, указанной в руководстве по [использованию сервера](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) aiohttp. Запускается из директории polls командой, подобной python -m aiohttpdemo_polls. Проект работает с Postgresql. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с завертыванием всего этого хозяйства в Docker.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.10
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get -qq update
run apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt install postgresql -y
RUN cd ~ && ls -la
RUN ./install.sh
RUN cd mlhttp/polls/
CMD ["python", "-m", "mlhttp_polls"]
```

файл, однако, далеко не закончен, поэтому не рабочий. Тонкости с установкой пакетов и зависимостей для проектов Python уже пройдены. Проблема в том, как подойти к конечной команде CMD.

Comment: При построении изображения докер использует контекст - по умолчанию, ту директорию, в которой был вызван билд, поэтому стоит использовать целиком директорию проекта, чтобы контекст включал в себя все необходимое. Вместо `RUN cd` лучше использовать директиву `WORKDIR`

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте 2 образа:

1. python и необходимые библиотеки к нему
2. postgresql - его можно взять готовый [официальный образ](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)

Для удобства запуска используйте [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/)

Образ с python тоже можно взять [готовый официальный](https://store.docker.com/images/python). Dockerfile может выглядеть примерно так

```
 FROM python:3.5-slim

 COPY . /srv/

 WORKDIR /srv/mlhttp/polls
 RUN pip install -e .

 CMD python -m mlhttp_polls
```